# Exchange Mailbox Sharing Issues

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, exchange-2010

Exchange 2010 running on Win 2012 Standard (VM). Users using Outlook 2010

Shared mailbox between 3 users for one mail address. One user is receiving up-to date data, other users dont have the same data/emails.

The same user has a full view of everything that came in from Friday->Monday, Around 20 new emails, the other users have about 6 "NEW" emails in the same mailbox.

This is a secondary mailbox for all users.

Have so far. Manually updated from outlook, recreated profiles, checked view settings and reset using the outlook cmd switch, restarted information store and made sure mailboxes are mounted correctly.

Anything else anyone can think off?

Comment: Same filters for all 3 users?

Comment: all set to off..

Answer (score 0):

We've found that having the user who only sees some of the messages add and remove a search from the Outlook search box seems to fix the problem.